# Prevent opening a second instance

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, wxpython

What's the easiest way to check if my program is already running with WxPython under Windows? Ideally, if the user tries to launch the program a second time, the focus should return to the first instance (even if the window is minimized).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94274/return-to-an-already-open-application-when-a-user-tries-to-open-a-new-instance) is similar but the answer is for VB.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [wx.SingleInstanceChecker](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.SingleInstanceChecker-class.html). See [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/OneInstanceRunning) for more information on how to use it, and [this post](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Mail/Message/wxPython-users/3707388) tells about finding the running instance (you have to use pywin32 functions for this, there's nothing built into wxPython AFAIK).