# Return to an already open app when a user tries to open a new instance if same version?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to open up an existing instance if my program is already running only if its running the same version.  I noticed that this question was asked for only the the name exists, but what if the version is older, I just want to notify the user that an older version is still running, please remove older version before starting this version.

The other link is this one:
[Return to an already open application when a user tries to open a new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94274/return-to-an-already-open-application-when-a-user-tries-to-open-a-new-instance)  but they don't talk about closing an instance if an older or newer version is detected.

Comment: get all process list and in foreach assembly name, version and etc. And if you find same assemblyName and version - close your instance.

Comment: Is it possible to merge these two together... whoops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the easiest way, make check like this:

```
foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcesses())
            if (proc.MainModule.FileName == Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
                //Shutdown your copy.
```

But more complex thing could be like this:

```
foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (proc.Id == Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id) continue;
            var currName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
            var procName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(proc.MainModule.FileName);
            if (currName.FullName == procName.FullName && /*and other parameters*/)
                return;
        }
```

Good luck!

P.S.:"But be careful - "GetAssemblyName" works only for managed code assemblies, so make it in try-catch wrap."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is it possible to go more in depth on a decision tree if its a newer version, current version, and an older version.  I know the windows setup can perform certain operations to detect this. thx